# Segmentation error in C while allocation memory

Tags: c, memory-management

I am a total begginer at C programming and am trying to write a program that reads the value of "stat" file in /proc/. It works for the first few entries, but then it returns "Segmentation error (core dumped)".
So far I found out that the error has to do with the allocation of memory, but I cant seem to find a way to fix it.
My code so far is:

```
char* readFile(char* filename)
{
 FILE *fp;
    struct stat buf;
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    stat(filename,&buf);
    char *string = malloc(buf.st_size);
    char *s;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
            s=malloc(1024);
            fgets(s,1024,fp);
            s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';
            strcat(string,s);
    }
    return string;

}

char* readStat(char* path, int statNumber)
{

  char* str = malloc(sizeof(readFile(path)));
  str = readFile(path);
  char * pch = malloc(sizeof(str));
  char * vals;
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  int i = 1;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
  if(i == statNumber)
        vals = pch;
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
  }
  return vals;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the

```
s=malloc(1024);
```

should not into the while it should be oitside the while loop and before the while.

And free it before leaving the function:

```
free(s);
```

2) add

```
string[0] = '\0';
```

just after

```
char *string = malloc(buf.st_size);
```

Otherwise the `strcat` will not work properly

3) You do not need to allocate memory for `str` pointer because the `readFile` function already did

```
char* str = malloc(sizeof(readFile(path)));
```

Just replaced with

```
char* str;
```

4) And also replace

```
char * pch = malloc(sizeof(str));
```

by

```
char * pch = str;
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you don't allocate space for the terminator for the `string` variable. You also need to terminate it before you can use it as a destination for `strcat`.

To continue, when you do `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of the *pointer* and **not** what it points to. You have this problem in `readStat`.

You also have memory leaks, in that you call `readFile` twice, but never free the memory allocated in it. Oh, and one of the memory allocations in `readFile` is not needed at all.

And there's another memory leak in that you allocate memory for `pch`, but you loose that pointer when you assign the result of the `strtok` call. `strtok` returns a pointer to the string in the `strtok` call, so no need to allocate memory for it (which you didn't attempt to free anyway).

Answer (score 0):

s=malloc(1024); should not be in loop, you should allocate the memory once and reset s with NULL before use next time in loop.
Also you should make a habit to free the memory after its usage.